# Как преобразовать формулы в значения во всей книге Excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Нужно разорвать все абсолютно ссылки во всей книге python-скриптом, но чтобы значения остались. Можно макросом.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Тут описано много способов, посмотрите что вам подходит! В том числе с макросами.
https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/11/215/

Comment: Нашла подходящее!

Comment: Рад, что ссылка оказалась полезной, однако ответы-ссылки на stackoverflow не приветствуются, так как часто устаревают. Если нашли подходящее -- поделитесь конкретным способом в ответе, возможно это пригодится тем, кто будет читать эту тему в поисках аналогичного вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Это решение мне помогло. Пример макроса:

```
Sub Formulas_To_Values_Book()
'преобразование формул в значения во всей книге'
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Здесь не принято публиковать код картинками. Посмотрите, я поправил удалённый ответ.

Comment: Перенёс из удалённого ответа код, в следующий раз попробуйте самостоятельно проделать подобную операцию: код картинкой и правда очень неудобен в использовании. Представьте, вам понравился какой-то код, вы его хотите скопировать и вставить, ан нет, приходится перенабирать, по пути возможны опечатки и ошибку. В общем, не очень комфортно.